# mongodb database problem that erases itself

Tags: linux, database, mongodb, ubuntu, configuration

I have a problem with my mongodb ubuntu server database, it erases after a few days, for the installation I followed its commands, which came from a tutorial from digital ocean

```
curl -fsSL https://www.mongodb.org/static/pgp/server-4.4.asc | sudo apt-key add -
echo "deb [arch = amd64, arm64] https://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu focal / mongodb-org / 4.4 multiverse" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongodb-org-4.4.list
sudo apt update
sudo apt install mongodb-org
sudo systemctl start mongod.service
sudo systemctl enable mongod
```

the only modification after that I made it is this to be able to access remotely with robo3T:

```
/etc/mongod.conf
. . .
# network interfaces
net:
   port: 27017
   bindIp: 127.0.0.1, my server ip
```

I have tried on several OVH DIgital ocean host I still have the same problem I do not understand why my collections are erased by themselves.

Comment: Before listening on a publicly accessible IP address, you should enable authentication.

Comment: I guess, it is not a problem of ubuntu or digital ocean. But you might enhance  your security configuration.
You should protect directly access of the database server or machine as well as add the authentication mechanism at database level.